# problem with GetDate() in asp.net

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have problem with GetDate() method.When i am creating any new user,in DateTime field Date is coming correctly time is not coming correctly,it should show generate always system date and time.Ex:2/6/2009 12:00:00 AM,2/7/2009 12:00:00 AM,2/8/2009 12:00:00 AM etc. I mean here 
date is changing but system time is not changing.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NewUser
(
@UserName varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@EmailId varchar(50),
@DateTime Date
)
AS
insert into Login(UserName,Password,EmailId,DateTime)
       values(@UserName,@Password,@EmailId,GetDate())


com.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

Comment: Do you want to use your web server's datetime, or the SQL Server's datetime?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest two changes:

- Change the parameter of the stored procedure to [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) instead of just [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx). (There are other options as well, such as [`datetimeoffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx).) The date type *only* stores the date, so it's not surprising that you're not seeing any times :) You'll need to change the table as well if its schema uses a `date` column.
- Don't convert the parameter value to a string when you're calling it. Use

  ```
  com.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
  ```

You might also want to consider using UTC instead of the local time on the server.

EDIT: splattne's absolutely right - by calling GetDate in the stored proc, the value of your parameter is irrelevant. Assuming you actually want to use the parameter, change the body of your stored proc to:

```
   insert into Login(UserName, Password, EmailId, DateTime)
   values(@UserName, @Password, @EmailId, @DateTime)
```

Double check the type of `Login.DateTime` though!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using getdate() in your stored procedure, your parameter @`DateTime` is obsolete. According to your code sample, it will be ignored.

So, the root of your problem must be somewhere else, if I correctly interpret your question.

I would check the **datatype of the date column in the SQL table**. The table declaration should be:

```
UserName varchar(50)
Password varchar(50)
EmailId  varchar(50)
DateTime DateTime  /* not "Date" */
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be using Sql 2008, with it's new Date datatype.

> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NewUser ( @UserName varchar(50), @Password varchar(50), @EmailId varchar(50), @DateTime Date )

Change the Sql code to use DateTime (and, the table, if necessary) and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Use Date of the DateTime.Now

```
com.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Also my suggestion is to use UTC instaed

```
com.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
```